# Appium starts app but does nothing on Samsung Galaxy Trend 2 [JAVA]

Tags: java, android, appium, samsung-mobile

I have an appium test program that works perfectly fine on a Samsung S3 with api 18. When I try to run this program on a Samsung Galaxy Trend 2 with api 19 the program starts running, the app gets installed and opens up fine but as soon as the first page comes up, nothing happens anymore. There are no errors (except for the timeout). Anyone had this experience before / can help me? Thanks alot!!

Comment: check for the locators you are using on that screen again.

Comment: checked via the ui automator the locators are the same...

Comment: not sure then..can't say anything without debug.